# How to access the value of an incoming push notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, notifications

How can I access the title of an incoming push notification?

```
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        self.numberOfNotifications += 1
    }

    // Print full message.
    print("Message: ", userInfo)

    //completionHandler([])

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    let data = userInfo.values as []//I would like to access the data here...

    completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
}
```

**Above I receive a notification I would like to check the title for specific text. How can I access the test as string to do this?**

Answer (score 0):

The title key will be inside aps["alert"] dictionary. 
A typical push notification message will look like this

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "title" : "Sample Title",
            "body" : "Hello World"
        },
        "badge" : 5
    }
}
```

The message can be accessed like this -

```
guard let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: AnyObject],
    let alert = aps["alert"] as? [String:Any],
    let body = alert["body"] as? String,
    let title = alert["title"] as? String
else {
  // handle any error here
  return
}
```

For further information you can check documentation provided by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH17-SW1).

Comment: I tried this and it always runs the else block despite the notif being there

Comment: I get nil for let aps = userInfo["aps"]

Comment: Please update the code so that we can see how you are accessing the aps array. Also share a sample of aps array.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this:

```
        let data = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: AnyObject]
    if let alert = data?["alert"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
        completionHandler([])
    } else {
        completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
    }
```